# Loading mock of $modal in Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have following question :

Suppose I have module

```
angular.module('myModule',['$strap'] );//module depends on AngularStrap
```

myModule has service defined as following :

```
angular.module('myModule').service('myModuleService', ['$modal', function ($modal) 
{ ....
}); //depends on $modal service from AngularStrap
```

Now I need to test myModuleService and I need to mock $modal service 
In test ( jasmine based ) myModuleService loaded  as following

```
var modalMock = jasmine.createSpy();
..
angular.mock.module('myModule');
...
$provide.value('$modal', modalMock);
..
angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
// Initialize the service under test instance
   myService = $injector.get('myModuleService');      
});
```

The problem is when myModuleService is loaded , also real $modal service is loaded and NOT mock of the $modal.
The question is: what is missing here in order to load myService with mockModal and not with real $modal ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm missing some of your test implementation details, but the following works:

```
describe('mock modal', function () {
    var modalMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('modal', ['show']),
        service;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('myModule');
        angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('$modal', modalMock);
        });

        angular.mock.inject(function (myModuleService) {
            // Initialize the service under test instance
            service = myModuleService;
        });
    });

    it('mocks modal', function () {
        service.foo();
        expect(modalMock.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

You can find the full [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/RYPwC/)